# How do I run a jQuery script on a post before it is published on Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This script should add the html necessary to create a text-block over images in a specific class.

I have to manually add several hundred images into Wordpress pages and add the class as I go along. That is tedious enough so I want to be able to just go back and run the script to add the html into the page where it belongs.

I figured there must be a simpler way so I wrote my first ever script after 2 days of trial and error and learned a TON! Yay me.  Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3ju8sn6/10/) which is exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

html before script

```
<figure><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg"><img class="notplus" width="400px" height="auto" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg"></a><figcapton>the figcaption</figcapton></figure>

<figure><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg"><img class="plus" width="400px" height="auto" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg"></a><figcapton>the figcaption</figcapton></figure>
```

css

```
/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
    position: relative;
}

/* Bottom right text */
.text-block {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.plus {
    border: 7px solid #818a91;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

script

```
 var htmlcon = [
  '<div class="container"></div>',
 ]
var htmltex = [
  '<div class="text-block">the new text</div>',
]
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.plus').closest('a').append(htmlcon),
    $('.container').append(htmltex);
});
```

the end result should be

```
<figure><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg"><img class="plus" width="400px" height="auto" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg"></a><div class="container"><div class="text-block">the new text</div></div><figcapton>the figcaption</figcapton></figure>
```

So, I want to be able to add images in the post editor all at once, then run the script so it adds the divs where they belong, then save and publish.

Comment: you can simply create a short code and render required result based on input i guess? because i think the new text is dynamic ryt? So simply create a short code with parameters for images and content and return the required result

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The text will be the same as there will not be more than one special class.  So, the images are already rendered with the [caption] (.wp-caption+.wp-caption-text) shortcode in the editor and the output is the <figure> and <figure caption>.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the text is not dynamic as suggested in the comments all you need is some js on dom loaded.

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var plusImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('figure .plus'));
    var newText = '<div class="container"><div class="text-block">the new text</div></div>';

    plusImages.forEach( function(plusImage) {
      plusImage.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newText)
    })

  });
```

To clarify, this won't change the DB but just the frontend.